# Is it possible to nominate different validators at the same time with the same stash account?

Tags: validator, stash

As title says, I'm wondering if this is at all possible

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can but it is advised to use your Controller account (also advised to be different than your Stash account) to do that.

A good place to start to learn about how to nominate is :

- [Become a Nominator on Polkadot](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-guides-how-to-nominate-polkadot)

> Nominators are recommended to set up separate stash and controller
> accounts.

- [How do I stake (nominate) on Polkadot?](https://support.polkadot.network/support/solutions/articles/65000168057-how-do-i-stake-nominate-on-polkadot-)
- [Nominating/Staking on Polkadot and Kusama with Bill Laboon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NYs9oWAbzbE) (2020)
- [Picking Validators to Nominate (Stake) in Polkadot](https://youtu.be/ZMzhM1m4I-k) (2020)
- [How to Nominate / Stake on Polkadot? - A Beginner's Guide](https://youtu.be/FCXC0CDhyS4) (2021)

Take into account that the 3 videos are a little bit old but still quite useful. More up to date info is in our wiki and support pages that are listed first. Hope some of this is helpful for you.